# Python import pdfplumber error " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet' "

Tags: import, python-3.7, modulenotfounderror, chardet

I encountered an error while importing pdfplumber in Python3, indicating module chardet is missing. However, running pip list from the cmd confirms that the package is installed, version 3.0.4. Anyone had similar experience? Any resolution?

**Error Message:**

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pdfminer\utils.py in <module>
      3 """
      4 import struct
----> 5 import chardet  # For str encoding detection
      6 
      7 # from sys import maxint as INF doesn't work anymore under Python3, but PDF

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
```

[Error: No module named chardet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ari0b.png)

Comment: I encountered the same error while using pdfplumber.